# PHP function to retrieve all images and their attributes from given html string and save to array and returns array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to write php function to retrieve all images attributes like src,alt, height, width from given html string and store those attributes into array result. i need this function to return the array result for further processing like saving into database, thumbnail creation ...etc.

i have wrote the following function but i am not satisfied as i am not able to extract elements other then scr

```
 $url = '<ul> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_sliderfashionshoot.jpg"/> </li> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_1.jpg"/> </li> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_2.jpg"/> </li> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_5.jpg"/> </li> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_4.jpg"/> </li> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_3.jpg"/> </li> <li> <img src="http://www.sayidaty.net/sites/default/files/imagecache/645xauto/01/04/2015/1427896207_6.jpg"/> </li> </ul> ';

function getItemImages($content)
{
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

  if($elements->length >= 1) {
    $url = array();
    $title = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $url[] = $element->getAttribute('src');
        $Title[] = $element->getAttribute('title');
    }
    return ($url);
}
```

Comment: It's probably because `src` is the only attribute in your `img` tags; I don't see `title=` anywhere in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Some inefficient code with lots of explodes

```
$a = explode("<img",$html);
for($j = 0; j <count($a) -1; $j++)
{
$codes = explode(">",$a[j+1]);
$codes = $codes[0];
$codes = explode("=",$codes);
for($i = 0; i < count($codes) -1; $i++)
{
  $name = explode(" ",$codes[i]);
  $value = explode("\"",$codes[i+1]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$field = '<img src="public/image/sun.png" title="This is such a sunny day" />';
$attrs = simplexml_load_string($field);
var_dump($attrs);
```

then the obj you will get will be

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["src"]=>
    string(20) "public/image/sun.png"
    ["title"]=>
    string(24) "This is such a sunny day"
  }
}
```

and it will contain all the tag's attributes.